# c++ nested class unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

i trying to implement nested c++ class B in singleton class A.

this is library and it build fine.

but when i trying to link it with application, get link error message.

any hint very appreciated!

basically, i want to keep access B from outside of class A.

> a.lib(aa.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   __thiscall A::B::B(void)" ...

```
class A // singleton 
{

//...
private:
 class B{//...}; 
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> var;

}
```

EDIT:
 class B has definition(B.cpp) and header (B.h)

i am trying to hide B.h and make B nested class.

if i include "B.h" it compile and link fine, but then open B class to outside..

EDIT:
 solved! thanks to molbdnilo

> Did you define the B class inside A? That is, class A::B { ... }; and
>   void A::B::foo(Bar baz) { ... }. – molbdnilo

Edit: this is applied source code.

```
// A.h
class A // singleton 
{
//...
private:
 class B; 
 static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> var;
}

// A.cpp
#include "B.h"
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A::B>> A::var;

// B.h
#include "A.h"
class A::B
{
//...
};
```

EDIT: found another simple solution, just excluded class B in class A. i don't have to expose anything from class B.

```
// private.h
extern std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> var;

//A.cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> var;
```

Comment: It's complaining that you declared a constructor for class B, but didn't actually implement it.  You should show more code (i.e. complete minimum, viable, example).

Comment: @selbie i edited my question.

Comment: Did you *define* the `B` class inside `A`? That is, `class A::B { ... };` and `void A::B::foo(Bar baz) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the class B private; I would suggest forward declaring it in the header.

In the cpp you can write the following:

```
class A::B final {
    // All code for B
};
```

If you do it this way; you might also want to move the implementation of Ctor, Dtor, Copy/Move Ctor and Copy/Move assignment to the cpp and/or make them deleted.